# Implicit declaration of function even after header inclusion

Tags: c

I'm having trouble using both the functions listed below in my c program main because of the implicit declaration error to the twos function.  Could someone please advise.
Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
float twoxaverage(int n, float t__scores[]);

float getaverage(int n, float t_scores[])
{    int sum=0; float average=0; int i;
     for (i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
          sum=sum + t_scores[i];
     }


     average=(float)sum/(float)n;
     return(average);
 }

 float twoxaverage(int n, float t__scores[])
 {   float mult;
     mult=2*(getaverage( n, t__scores));
     return (mult);
 }

 int main()
 {
     int t_score[]={1,2,3,4}; 
     float twox;
     twox=twoaverage4,t_score);
     float twoxaverage(int n, float t__scores[]);

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? Which function is implicitly declared?

Comment: The code isn't even syntactically valid. Please post the actual code with full details of the error.

Comment: What are you trying to do by including `float twoxaverage(int n, float t__scores[]);` in the main? I think you do not need this.

Answer (score 1):

Your main should move from:

```
int main(){

    int t_score[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; float twox;
    twox = twoaverage4, t_score); float twoxaverage(int n, float t__scores[]);

    return 0;
}
```

TO:

```
int main(){

    int t_score[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; 
    float twox;
    twox = twoxaverage(4, t_score);

    return 0;
}
```

as a start.

I might also simplify your:

```
float getaverage(int n, float t_scores[]){    
    int sum=0; float average=0; int i;
     for (i=0; i<n; i++){
      sum=sum + t_scores[i];
     }

     average=(float)sum/(float)n;
     return(average);
 }
```

TO:

```
float getaverage(int n, float t_scores[]){    
    float average=0; int i;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        average = average + t_scores[i];
    }

     return(average / (float)n);
 }
```

This uses one less variable and performs the same math.

Comment: While good stylistically, I don't see how that'll make a difference.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - do you not see his main routine, particularly the line "twox = twoaverage4, t_score); float twoxaverage(int n, float t__scores[]);"???

Comment: Oh yes, I missed his glaring syntax error. :)

Comment: Maybe helpful to point out explicitly that the actual error mentioned in the title was caused by a simple misspelling of `twoxaverage` as `twoaverage`. First thing to look for when investigating mysterious implicit declarations.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - TRUE THAT, but I think the OP is fairly inexperienced, so by virtue, he doesn't no any better than to ask with what the compiler is telling him.

Comment: @trumpetlicks: Well, the OP doesn't seem to be alert enough to even post his real code, but it may be helpful to others who take the time to search for "implicit declaration" before they ask a question.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - Again, True that, LOL.  good point.  Been seeing a lot of what I think to be homework on SO lately, what about you?

Answer (score 0):

In this line you have at least two typos in one identifier

```
twox=twoaverage4,t_score);float twoxaverage(int n, float t__scores[]);
```

Instead of

```
twox=twoaverage4,t_score);
```

there shall be

```
twox = twoxaverage(4,t_score);
```

Also the declaration of the function that follows is unnecessary. So instead of

```
twox=twoaverage4,t_score);float twoxaverage(int n, float t__scores[]);
```

you can write simply

```
twox = twoxaverage(4,t_score);
```

I think you have not only to get the average but also to output it. So you could at least add statement

```
std::cout << twox << std::endl;
```

Or if it is a C program then you could use `printf` instead of C++ `operator <<` to output twox

Also take into account that your function getaverage is wrong. You convert float numbers to int when add them to sum

```
           float getaverage(int n, float t_scores[])
           {    int sum=0; float average=0; int i;
                for (i=0; i<n; i++)
           {
                sum=sum + t_scores[i];
           }


           average=(float)sum/(float)n;
           return(average);
           }
```

The valid function could look the following way

```
           float getaverage( int n, const float t_scores[] )
           {    
                float sum = 0.0f;

                for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
                {
                     sum += t_scores[i];
                }

                return ( n == 0 ? 0.0f : sum / n );
           }
```

Or if you use an old C compiler then the function can be written as

```
           float getaverage( int n, const float t_scores[] )
           {    
                float sum = 0.0f;
                int i = 0;

                for ( ; i < n; i++ )
                {
                     sum += t_scores[i];
                }

                return ( n == 0 ? 0.0f : sum / n );
           }
```

Function twoxaverage could be simplified the following way

```
inline float twoxaverage( int n, const float t__scores[] )
{   
     return ( 2 * getaverage( n, t__scores ) );
}
```